# Sequelize request error SequelizeEagerLoadingError

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I’m new with sequelize I’m trying to make a request with associate tables

I have a first model called `Experience`

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    const Experience = sequelize.define('experience', {
        internalId: {
            type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
            unique: true,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        label: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            unique: false,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        picture: {
            type: DataTypes.TEXT,
            unique: false,
            allowNull: true,
        },
        type: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            validate: {
                isIn: {
                    args: [[
                        'generic',
                        'specific',
                    ]],
                    msg: 'Must be a valid type',
                },
            },
            unique: false,
            allowNull: true,
        },
        author: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            unique: false,
            allowNull: true,
            defaultValue: 'import',
        },
        isActive: {
            type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
            defaultValue: true,
        },
    });

    Experience.associate = (models) => {
        Experience.belongsToMany(models.Tag, {
            as: 'Tags',
            through: models.ExperienceTag,
        });
    };

    return Experience;
};
```

a second called `Tags`

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    const Tag = sequelize.define('tag', {
        internalId: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            unique: true,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            unique: false,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        author: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            unique: false,
            allowNull: true,
            defaultValue: 'import',
        },
        isActive: {
            type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
            defaultValue: true,
        },
    });

    Tag.associate = (models) => {
        Tag.belongsToMany(models.Experience, {
            as: 'Experiences',
            through: models.ExperienceTag,
        });
    };

    return Tag;
};
```

The association table name was `ExperienceTags`
I would like get all the `Experience`who have a `tagId = 44`

This is my request:

```
Experience.findAll({
        include: [{
            model: ExperienceTag,
            where: { tagId: 44 },
        }],
    })
        .then((results) => {
            winston.warn(JSON.stringify(results, null, 2));
            res.status(200)
                .send(results);
        })
        .catch(error => res.status(500)
            .send({ error: error.toString() }));
```

But when I execute it I have an error like:

```
{
  "error": "SequelizeEagerLoadingError: experienceTag is not associated to experience!"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you like to include `Tag` rather than `ExperienceTag`, the following example may help you

```
Experience.findAll({
        include: [{
            model: Tag, //model name which you want to include
            as: 'Tags', // you have to pass alias as you used while defining
            where: { tagId: 44 },
        }],
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I think , you need to add `as: 'Experiences'` , in your include as you have defined association with alias

Change this

```
Experience.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: ExperienceTag,
        where: { tagId: 44 },
    }],
})
```

With

```
Experience.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: ExperienceTag,
        as: 'Experiences', // <---- HERE
        where: { tagId: 44 },
    }],
})
```

Comment: not working but if i try with

````
Experience.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: Tag,
        as: 'Tags', 
        where: { id: 44 },
    }],
})
```

it's look like good